# Android- display URL in a text view not displaying

Tags: android, string, url, textview

I'm trying to have a url path display in a text view and marquee it on screen. But for some reason its no displaying. I'm think my code is correct.

Where i'm getting the url and coverting to string (this is in a service):

```
String path = ((PlaylistFile)playlistItems.get(currentPlaylistltemNumber)).getFilePath();
                        Log.d(TAG, "got the path");
                        //String[] path2 = path.split("/");
                        Log.d(TAG, "split the path");
                        artistInfoBOJ = path;
                        Log.d(TAG, "set to artist info boj");
```

I then create my text view in another class and link it to the text:

```
//artist info stuff
    this.textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artistViewBOJ);
    Log.d(TAG,"create the text view");
    //textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    test = BOJAudioService.artistInfoBOJ;
    Log.d(TAG, "set test = to string");
    textView.setText(test);
    Log.d(TAG,"set text to text view");
```

what appears in my log cat:

```
08-04 12:22:44.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioActivity(17287): create the text view
08-04 12:22:44.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioActivity(17287): set test = to string
08-04 12:22:44.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioActivity(17287): set text to text view
08-04 12:22:44.655: WARN/KeyboardStateImpl(253): EditorInfo provided is null or not valid, defaulting to dumb mode!
08-04 12:22:45.104: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17287): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 50% free 2850K/5639K, external 2569K/2982K, paused 25ms+5ms
08-04 12:22:45.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioService(17287): got the path
08-04 12:22:45.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioService(17287): split the path
08-04 12:22:45.574: DEBUG/BOJAudioService(17287): set to artist info boj
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Whats the problem? Can you post the Exception? Also - debug and step through to make sure test isn't null.

Comment: @Jack. Well the text is not displaying. I added what appears on my log cat. but everything seems to be running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Log.d(TAG, "set test = to string");
```

to

```
Log.d(TAG, "set test = to " + test);
```

to see what test is

Comment: ok. So this is what displayed: 08-04 13:01:45.208: DEBUG/BOJAudioActivity(19110): set test = tonull. So it is null. hmmm

Comment: i suppose so. Any ideas of why it could be `null`?

Comment: Set some break points and debug in your BOJAudioService ... specifically where artistInfoBOJ gets instantiated and set.